How to match legend bubble sizes in a bubble piechart map in R
When using bubble piecharts to map counts of 3 categories in different sites across a map, I cannot find a solution for indicating accurately each (bubble) piechart size in the legend.
pacman::p_load(ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr, sf, rnaturalearth, rnaturalearthdata, scatterpie)
#my summarised data
coropango_summary <- data.frame(site = c("KOU","LMB","MMG","MND","MRG","MSS","NDO","OYN","PTK","TRQ"),
                                lat = c(1.80,0.41,0.34,1.34,1.53,0.47,0.11,1.36,-0.59,-3.03),
                                long = c(12.29,10.13,12.52,13.12,11.56,11.34,10.45,11.34,12.49,11.29),
                                Bos = c(2,45,1,1,1,0,1,2,0,1),
                                Gnu = c(2,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1),
                                undet = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0),
                                host_sum = c(4,46,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2)
)
#get map of Gabon and its neighbours
central_africa_map <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", continent = "Africa", returnclass = "sf")
gabon_map <- subset(central_africa_map, admin == "Gabon")
neighboring_countries <- subset(central_africa_map, admin != "Gabon" & sovereignt %in% c("Equatorial Guinea", "Cameroon", "Republic of the Congo"))
gabon_regions <- ne_states(country = "Gabon", returnclass = "sf")
ocean_color <- "steelblue1"
host_counts <- unique(sort(coropango_summary$host_sum))

gabon <- ggplot(data = gabon_map) +
  geom_sf(fill = "white", color = "black") +
  geom_sf(data = neighboring_countries, fill = "grey95", color = "black", linetype = "solid") +
  geom_sf(data = gabon_map, fill = "white", color = "black", linewidth = .5) +
  geom_sf(data = gabon_regions, fill = NA, color = "darkgrey", linetype = "dotted", linewidth = .4) +
  geom_scatterpie(data = coropango_summary, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = site,
                                                r = sqrt(host_sum)/10, size = host_sum),
                  cols = c("Bos","Gnu", "undet"),
                  color = NA, alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_scatterpie_legend(radius = sqrt(coropango_summary$host_sum)/10,
                         x = 8, y = -2.95, n = 4, labeller = function(value) host_counts) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Bos" = "goldenrod2","Gnu" = "darkgreen","undet" = "firebrick4")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "black", linewidth = 0.2, linetype = "solid") +
  annotate("text", x = 12.2, y = 2.7, label = "Cameroon", size = 4, fontface = "bold") +
  annotate("text", x = 10.6, y = 1.62, label = "Equatorial\nGuinea", size = 4, fontface = "bold") +
  annotate("text", x = 13.5, y = -3.1, label = "Republic of the\nCongo", size = 4, fontface = "bold") +
  labs(fill = "Host") +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(7, 15), ylim = c(-4, 3), expand = FALSE) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = ocean_color, color = NA),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_text(),
    panel.grid = element_blank()
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0))

The results is a map where the minimum and maximum bubbles seem to be of the right size, but not the intermediates (sizes 2 and 4) which are much larger then the corresponding scatterpies. Matching these bubbles to the scatterpies on the map is the main issue. Here is what I managed so far [Result](https://i.sstatic.net/cwFPJWfg.png)
Secondly, the mapping of `host_sum` appears in legend and I have no idea how to remove it.  I think that the circle areas should be matched somewhere, but I cannot figure out how and where. Any help is greatly appreciated.   I have tried mapping each size (1,2,4,46) as separate `geom_scatterpie` but could not control the sizes of untransformed values.
Also, I have tried [creating the legend separately](Create a concentric circle legend for a ggplot bubble chart), but it did not turn out well, likely due to my limited understanding of R.

To match the radiuses in the scatterpie legend with the scatterpies use the breaks= argument instead of radius=. The "issue" is that under the hood geom_scatterpie_legend will choose nice breaks using scales::breaks_extended based on the vector of values passed to radius=. Fro your second issue, drop size = host_sum from geom_scatterpie:
library(ggplot2)
library(scatterpie)

ggplot(data = gabon_map) +
  geom_sf(fill = "white", color = "black") +
  geom_sf(data = neighboring_countries, fill = "grey95", color = "black", linetype = "solid") +
  geom_sf(data = gabon_map, fill = "white", color = "black", linewidth = .5) +
  geom_sf(data = gabon_regions, fill = NA, color = "darkgrey", linetype = "dotted", linewidth = .4) +
  geom_scatterpie(
    data = coropango_summary, aes(
      x = long, y = lat, group = site,
      r = sqrt(host_sum) / 10
    ),
    cols = c("Bos", "Gnu", "undet"),
    color = NA, alpha = 0.6
  ) +
  geom_scatterpie_legend(
    breaks = sqrt(host_counts) / 10,
    x = 8, y = -2.95, n = 4,
    labeller = function(value) host_counts
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Bos" = "goldenrod2", "Gnu" = "darkgreen", "undet" = "firebrick4")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "black", linewidth = 0.2, linetype = "solid") +
  annotate("text", x = 12.2, y = 2.7, label = "Cameroon", size = 4, fontface = "bold") +
  annotate("text", x = 10.6, y = 1.62, label = "Equatorial\nGuinea", size = 4, fontface = "bold") +
  annotate("text", x = 13.5, y = -3.1, label = "Republic of the\nCongo", size = 4, fontface = "bold") +
  labs(fill = "Host") +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(7, 15), ylim = c(-4, 3), expand = FALSE) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = ocean_color, color = NA),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_text(),
    panel.grid = element_blank()
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0))



It works. Any idea if the circle labels can be separated without reducing fontsize ?
